# MySQL Workbench Error Code 29: (Errcode13 -Permission denied)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Can anyone please let me know why I keep getting a permission denied error even though I am logged in as the admin? I am trying to load a text file into a table in mysql workbench.

```
use alpha;  
drop table raw_finance_data;  
create table raw_finance_data 
(  
    Company         varchar(256),  
    Profit_Center   varchar(256),  
    Year            varchar(256),  
    Scenario        varchar(256),  
    Account         varchar(256),  
    total           float  
);  

load data infile 'D:/Users/alpha/Documents/Excel/fin.txt' into table alpha.raw_finance_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I keep getting the error below. I am in the database as the admin.

```
Error Code: 29. File 'D:\Users\alpha\Documents\Excel\fin.txt' not found (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

Comment: Why on Earth would you have `Year` (or every other field for that matter) as `Varchar(256)`?

Comment: Is it file permissions?  Is the file there and do you have read priviliges to it? As well as Permission denied it also says "File 'D:\Users\alpha\Documents\Excel\fin.txt' not found"

Comment: Try putting local before the infile i.e. load data local infile etc

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your file is local to your client machine then you need to include 'local' i.e.

```
load data local infile 'D:/Users/alpha/Documents/Excel/fin.txt' into table alpha.raw_finance_data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```